# Unexpected Results with Paging after deploying application to IIS (MVC3, EF 4.3)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, windows-server-2008, iis-7.5

I am currently deployment on an MVC 3 website which uses Entity Framework 4.3 for database access.

The application works as expected in the Visual Studio development server but once it is deployed to the remote server the query reacts unexpectedly

It should display a sorted list and pages through that sorted data

I've tried restarting the web server and the physical server machine  to make sure the cache is gone and even tried using a clean IIS Site on the remote server with the same result.

[Edit]: I have also done a full delete and republish to a clean site as well

**On Development Machine**

[image: development machine]

**On the Remote Server**

[image]

**The code I am using to generate the tables:**

*Controller*

```
    [HttpGet]
    public virtual ActionResult Index(string filter = "", int? page = null)
    {

        page = page ?? 1;
        filter = filter.Trim().ToLower();
        int pageSize = Properties.Settings.Default.DefaultSPPageSize;



        int skipNum = (page.Value - 1) * pageSize;

        IQueryable<SamplePoint> spList;
        var points = new HashSet<string>(Settings.Default.SamplePointFilter.Split(','));


        if (filter != "")
            spList = db.SamplePoints.Where(e=> 
                        points.Any(p=> e.Id.StartsWith(p))
                     && e.Id.ToLower().Trim().StartsWith(filter.ToLower()))
            .OrderBy(o => o.Id);

        else
            spList = db.SamplePoints.Where(e =>
                        points.Any(p => e.Id.StartsWith(p))
                     && e.Id.Trim().StartsWith(filter)).OrderBy(o => o.Id);


        List<SamplePoint> pageItems;
        if (page != 0)
        {
            pageItems = spList.Skip(skipNum).Take(pageSize).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            pageItems = spList.OrderBy(o=> o.Id).ToList();
        }

        int _totPages = Convert.ToInt32(pageSize > 0 ? Math.Ceiling(((double)spList.Count() / (double)pageSize)) : 0);


        var vModel = new SamplePointListViewModel(pageItems, filter) { LocationList = FilterListItems, TotalPages = _totPages, CurrentPage = page.Value };

        return View(this.IsExcelRequest() ? MVC.Reports.Views.Excel.SamplePointList : MVC.Reports.Views.SamplePointList, vModel);
    }
```

Comment: Are you connecting to the same database?

Comment: yes it is the same database once it on the server it messes up the ordering tho its as if it is pulling the taken records with out ordering them first

Comment: your are ordering by id can you check if the IDs are the same on the server and the development machine ?

Comment: i am using the production database for development, testing and deployment so the same data is present for both configurations  and same code is present for both (not using compiler directives etc)

Comment: Does your production server have multiple files assigned to tempdb and SQL Server is generating a parallel execution plan for some insertion which results in rows being inserted with different orders and different identity values?

Comment: there is a seperate application that handles data insertion this is purely a reporting application  and this application is using oracle for the database which it seems i failed to mention in the original post the mvc application isn't doing anything in parallel if understand your question properly and there are 3 seperate external mechanisms inserting data to the database however i dont see how that explains the data being in order on the development server but out of order on the production server

Comment: What is the data type of ID? Are the machines identical in their architecture (x86 vs. x64 etc.)? Does the application behave as expected when using IIS on the local machine rather than Cassini?

Comment: the datatype is string ill try it in iis on my local machine and repost

Comment: It does appear as if the set on production is ordered, at least from the data that is available in the screen shot. Do the BE2 sample point ID's exist at all in the paged data when you run this in Production?

Comment: the production set data is all there it just isn't sorting across pages we made a sorting change immediately prior to the deployment to our production server my first guess is caching of the old assemblies on the server and iis/mvc not picking them up im currently waiting on a scheduled maintenance this afternoon to see if this fixes it

Comment: Let's see the source code for the View.

Comment: Also why not do a SQL profiler session?

Comment: Under what scenario would the "page" parameter be "0"?

Comment: its a debugging value to disable paging and show all results

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a code issue, more like a provider issue. Are you using the same EF provider on both environments?

Comment: closing question as i got laid off due to IT budget cuts =(

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the ASP.NET MVC version is the same on both machines (dev/prod). Other people [got problems](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCBetaAndRCUpgradesConfirmYourExpectationsAndVersionNumbersInProductionEnvironments.aspx) because of this.

Basically it happened that a newer version was int the production server's GAC.

Comment: mvc 3 is bin deployed with the application and have never used mvc 2 in the past

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is implement some kind of **logging** and write the output produced at intermediate levels to a log file.

If you are using VS ultimate edition you can a give a shot using [IntelliTrace](http://sdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336126.aspx). (I haven't used this tool though I heard about it)

Comment: unfortunately we dont have ultimate at work i have it home only =(

Answer (score 0):

```
spList = db.SamplePoints.Where(e=> 
                        points.Any(p=> e.Id.StartsWith(p))
                     && e.Id.ToLower().Trim().StartsWith(filter.ToLower()))
            .OrderBy(o => o.Id);
```

From your code above,

Is the **e.ID** the first column in your image above? if not, is **e.Id** the primary key and the IdentitySeed set to true? If so, this is your problem, since it is auto generated, this ID will be different in production database and the development database which causes the display differently.

Comment: Q1: I think I've mentioned this a couple times but the there is only 1 database there is no development db there is no data being written to the database by this application.

 Q2:Id is the primary key for the table and this an Oracle database identity seed is as far as i know a ms sql server option all data is maintained by another server application

Answer (score 0):

Are both servers have the same regional settings?

You use `string.ToLover` and `StartsWith` that will perform transformation based on current culture.

You should use overloaded versions of these methods with Invariant culture.